# Regex Value from CUSD

Tags: regex, vb.net

i have CUSD data like this:

"AT+CUSD=1,"*388#",15   OK    +CUSD: 0,"PulsaUTAMA Rp.3375. Aktif 01/12/16, Tenggang 31/12/16,SMSHarian 0 ke ISAT& 0  SMS ke Opr lain.Eklusif Arsenal+grts tlp 1jm,hub *465*4#",64  "

How to regex to get value :

- PulsaUTAMA Rp.{currency balance}
- Aktif {dd/mm/yyyy}
- Tenggang {dd/mm/yyyy}

Thank's

Comment: See http://ideone.com/ZY2LxZ

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew
It's working. You save my time... GBU

Answer (score 0):

This is code from @Wiktor Stribiżew, working perfectly.

```
Dim s As String = "AT+CUSD=1,""*388#"",15   OK    +CUSD: 0,""PulsaUTAMA Rp.3375. Aktif 01/12/16, Tenggang 31/12/16,SMSHarian 0 ke ISAT& 0  SMS ke Opr lain.Eklusif Arsenal+grts tlp 1jm,hub *465*4#"",64"
    Dim p As String = "PulsaUTAMA\s+Rp\.(?<balance>\d+)\.\s*Aktif\s*(?<date1>[\d/]+),\s*Tenggang\s*(?<date2>[\d/]+)"
    Dim res As Match = Regex.Match(s, p)
    If res.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine(res.Groups("balance").Value)
        Console.WriteLine(res.Groups("date1").Value)
        Console.WriteLine(res.Groups("date2").Value)
    End If
```